# Elastic Beanstalk compile php with ZipArchive enabled

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-extension

I need to set my PHP project to compile php with ZipArchive enabled. I am running php7 on Elastic Beanstalk and need help on how to write a ".ebextensions" file to accomplish this task. Can someone help me out here?

Thank!

Answer (score 6):

You can create this easily.

**1.** Create a directory ".ebextensions";
(If MAC, in your terminal run `mkdir .ebextensions` and `cd .ebextensions`)

**2.** Create a file php7zip.config so you have .ebextensions/php7zip.config `touch php7zip.config` 
**3.** paste this inside the file 
  `packages:
    yum:
      php70-zip: []` 
  Save the file.
**4.** Run `eb deploy`

There you go. You should have the extension install. You can use this same method to install other extensions on Elastic Beanstalk.

Goodluck

Comment: this broke my instance